# contact list from yahoo,hotmail,gmail and Facebook in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios5, gmail, hotmail, xmppframework

I am creating an iOS application.I have to implement a mail sending option as "Tell a friend" inside the application.For that I have to get the contacts list from the user's gmail,yahoo,man,Facebook etc.

I have used XMPP frame work,by using that I got the contact list from Facebook and gmail.
I found that yahoo is not supporting XMPP.I found this link (http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/objectivec/) for yahoo. But I think it will be better to use a single API/SDK for getting the contact list from all the account.

**My doubt is : ** Is there any common framework availabele for getting the contact list from all account?
If any body has idea then please help me.Thanks in advance